# using HashSet removing duplicates

Tags: c#, hashset

how can i remove duplicates using HashSet or if you have better idea please let me know but so far this is what i am doing...

i am trying to eliminate the duplicates and below code is what i am using....

```
HashSet<DropDownListClass> hashSetTopics = new HashSet<DropDownListClass>(); 

foreach (XmlNode node in topicNodes)
{
   string topicId = node.Attributes["TopicId"].Value;
   string topicName = node.Attributes["TopicName"].Value;
   hashSetTopics.Add(new DropDownListClass { Id = topicId, Name = topicName }); 
} 

the below code does removes the duplicates but the problem with the below is that i need a way to attach the id with name... at the end i am binding to dropdownlist.

HashSet<string> hashSetTopics1 = new HashSet<string>(); 

foreach (XmlNode node in topicNodes)
{
   string topicId = node.Attributes["TopicId"].Value;
   string topicName = node.Attributes["TopicName"].Value;
   hashSetTopics1.Add(topicName }); 
} 

DropDownList1.DataSource = hashSetTopics; /hashSetTopics1
DropDownList1.DataBind();


 public class DropDownListClass
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } 
    }
```

Comment: `Removing duplicates from a Hashset`. Man, a Hashset cannot have duplicates, that's the whole point of it.

Comment: @Darin I think he is asking how to use the Hashset to remove duplicates as a practice, not removing dupicates from the Hashset.

Comment: But then again he is doing from another hashset so I see the concern. :)

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of ways to do this.

One way would be to override the `Equals` method of your `DropDownListClass`. See [Guidelines for Overriding Equals and Operator ==](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Another would be to create an `EqualityComparer` derived class that does the comparison:

```
public DropDownComparer : EqualityComparer<DropDownListClass>
{
    public override bool Equals(DropDownListClass i1, DropDownListClass i2)
    {
        bool rslt = (i1.Id == i2.Id) && (i1.Name == i2.Name);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(DropDownListClass x)
    {
        return x.Id.GetHashCode() ^ x.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And when you create your `HashSet`:

```
DropDownComparer comparer = new DropDownComparer();
HashSet<DropDownListClass> hashSetTopics = new HashSet<DropDownListClass>(comparer);
```

That tells the `HashSet` code, "use my custom comparison function to compare items." Your first loop should work now.

Comment: where does the second half code codes? insdie the foreach loop? `HashSet<DropDownListClass> hashSetTopics = new HashSet<DropDownListClass>(comparer); ` i dont see how it will work unless i am missing something

Answer (score 2):

IComparible interface (IEqualityComparer): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx

you can use this code for generic equality projection

```
public sealed class ProjectionComparer<TValue, TProjection> : IEqualityComparer<TValue>
    {
        readonly Func<TValue, TProjection> _projection;

        public ProjectionComparer(Func<TValue, TProjection> projection)
        {
            projection.AssertParameterNotNull("projection");
            _projection = projection;
        }

        bool IEqualityComparer<TValue>.Equals(TValue x, TValue y)
        {
            var projectedX = _projection(x);
            var projectedY = _projection(y);

            return projectedX.Equals(projectedY);
        }

        int IEqualityComparer<TValue>.GetHashCode(TValue obj)
        {
            var projectedObj = _projection(obj);
            return projectedObj.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IList<ListItem> dropDownListItems = new List<ListItem>();

foreach (XmlNode node in topicNodes)
{
   string topicId = node.Attributes["TopicId"].Value;
   string topicName = node.Attributes["TopicName"].Value;
   dropDownListItems.Add(new ListItem(topicName, topicId)); 
} 

DropDownList1.DataSource = dropDownListItems.Distinct(); 
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

**EDIT**
I think you are getting dups in your HashSet because your the DropDownListClass isn't implementing IComparable

Below is an example of how duplicate data is making it's way into a HashSet.  The MyObject class should probably implement the interfeace IComparible.

```
public void Main()
{
    HashSet<MyObject> myObjects = new HashSet<MyObject>();
    bool success = myObjects.Add(new MyObject{ID = 1});
    success.Dump("First"); //Returns true

    success = myObjects.Add(new MyObject{ID = 1});

    success.Dump("Second"); //Returns true should have been false
}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class MyObject
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
}
```

You can even call Distinct() off of your original HashSet object but that just hides that it's broken.

Comment: the first method is getting rid of dupes but the problem with that is, how can i assign `DataTextField` and `DataTextValue` to the dropdownlsit?

Comment: i am not sure i understand your second method `MyObject` like how will it work with a real data scenario

Comment: @Abu I was giving an example as to why your HashSet was not having distinct values like it is supposed to. The MyObject class doesn't have a way to compare its self so it gets added to the HashSet as if it's not a duplicate, which is why in the above question the duplicates are being removed from an object that is already not supposed to have duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a dictionary - you get uniqueness based on the key, and the value can be anything.

```
Dictionary<string, DropDownListClass> topics = new Dictionary<string, DropDownListClass>(); 

foreach (XmlNode node in topicNodes)
{
   string topicId = node.Attributes["TopicId"].Value;
   string topicName = node.Attributes["TopicName"].Value;
   topics[topicName] = new DropDownListClass { Id = topicId, Name = topicName }; 
} 

DropDownList1.DisplayMember = "Name";
DropDownList1.ValueMember = "Id";
DropDownList1.DataSource = topics.Values;
DropDownList1.DataBind();
```

You could also probably implement an Equals method on DropDownListClass that compared based on the Id property.

Lastly, DropDownListClass could probably have a much better name, such as Topic.

Comment: won't that throw and exception on dup key entry?

Comment: how can i assign DataTextField and DataTextValue to the dropdownlsit?

Comment: @Cubicle.Jockey No, it will just replace the old value with the new one if one already exists.

Comment: @AbuHamzah Assuming DropDownList is a ComboBox or some other subclass of ListControl, set the DisplayMember and ValueMember properties.  I've updated the answer with an example.

Comment: @Chris sorry you are correct I had the Add method stuck in my head.